# How do I split a string and look for digits?

Tags: java

```
String[] tokens = s.split(' ');
    for(int i = 0; i < (tokens.length) - 1; ++i)
    {  
            if(isDigit(tokens[i]))
        {
            // Two numbers cannot be together without an operator.
            if(isDigit(tokens[i + 1]))
            {
                check = 1;
                break;
            }
            if((tokens[i + 1] == '(') )
            {
                check = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
           }
```

s is the string i'm splitting. after splitting i want to check whether each split part is a digit. i m not able to use isDigit because it can only be used on characters and here the split part is String.

**NOTE: i m writing a program for a calculator. if i use toCharArray() the more than one digit numbers will be split. eg. 23 will become 2 and 3 seperately.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int isDigit = false;
try
{
    Integer.parseInt(tokens[i])
    isDigit = true;
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{

}
```

Comment: what if the number is a float type?/

Answer (score 0):

YOu might use `Integer.parseInt(...)` if your number should be Integer (same for other types). It throws NumberFormatException on invalid number I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{    

if(isDigit(Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]))
{
   //Will come here if it is an integer
} 
 } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {

  //Will come here if it is not an integer

}
```

Comment: what if the number is float type??

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know if every token is a number?

```
try{
   Integer.parseInt(token)
   return true;
} catch (numberFormatException){
   return false;
}
```

or use apache commons lang http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/index.html

```
StringUtils.isNumeric()
```

Comment: what if the number is float type??

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `string.toCharArray()` method instead of `string.split()`, it produces an array of chars that can then be checked using `Character.isDigit(char)` method. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One way: use Integer.parse(token) and catch NumberFormatException for the ones that aren't numbers:

Or use token.toCharArray() and test the characters individually.